# How to iterate through a list of floating point numbers in python

Tags: python, list, floating-point, iterator

I am trying to go through a list of floating point numbers to sum up the list but I am getting the flowing error: TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable

Here is my code:

```
sum = 0.0
for x in range(avgListed):
    sum += x
```

I can't seem to figure it out, is there a way to make floats iterable?

Comment: Why not use

    sum(argListed)

?

Comment: Don't use  `list` as a name. It is a built-in function.

Comment: the list i want to iterate through, changed it in this example though

Comment: Show us what 'avgListed' exactly is?

Comment: AvgListed is a list of averages, about 500 of them

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is better:

```
s = sum(avgListed)
```

An example

```
>>> avgListed = [1.2, 3.3,4.6]
>>> sum(avgListed)
9.1
>>>
```

Comment: I am using Python 2.7.2: Python 2.7.2 (default, Jun 12 2011, 15:08:59) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

Comment: Ok thank you my issue us fixed, my problem was with the way I filled in avgListed

Answer (score 0):

```
sum = 0.0
for x in avgListed:
    sum+=x
```

You can use like that too or

```
sum = 0.0
for x in range(len(avgListed)):
    sum += avgListed[x]
```

Same work